# Can legendary Pokemon found using Mystery Part in Explorers of Sky reappear if they are not recruited?

Tags: pokemon-mystery-dungeon-explorers

I found a Celebi in Mystifying Forest, but it did not join my team. Will I need to start from my last save point, or can she/it be recruited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next time you go through the dungeon again, she/it will reappear. Just keep trying!

Legendaries in general will respawn when you defeated them, until you befriend them. So, it doesn't matter if it doesn't join you right away. To increase the odds of joining you, make your leader hold items which increase the chance of befriending Pokemon.

Comment: Celebi was recruited before the answer, but I kept the question open because the same thing happened at 13F with Darkrai.